# Keep Cell Blank When Applying Formula Until Data Entered - Using "Dates"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

First time posting. I am needing help with a mind-bender of a formula. Firstly, I am wanting to keep all cells blank until the referenced Cell is populated. So for this to work, a date will be entered in the referenced cell, i.e "Wednesday, 3 February 2021". From there I would like the following to happen:

- The "future date" cell to automatically add 6 weeks (Workdays only).

The current formula I use is: =WORKDAY([@[Next Scheduled AM Meeting]], 42)

This formula works great BUT when I drag down to populate cells bellow to copy the formula into cells below which have no date or cell to reference I get random dates which are understandable but I would like the formula to be set in these cells but keep the cell blank until the referenced cell is populated.

I've seen formulas like  =IF(OR(ISBLANK) etc.. but I honestly have no idea what it all means.

Essentially, I want to keep the Future Date Cell blank until the primary referenced cell is populated at which time the future Date Cell will automatically add 6 weeks (weekdays) to the original referenced date.

Your help is appreciated.

[Ref Excel Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkDr4.png)

Comment: Use `ISBLANK` function like `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",WORKDAY(A2,6))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(A2<>"",WORKDAY(A2,42),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Legend. Thank you. Two more things: